# How can I add quote to each element in list of string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, psql

I have a postgresql sql that return a list o element stored in column :

This is my sql :

```
SELECT quote_literal(value) AS cluster_values 
FROM process_configuration pc 
WHERE pc.parameter='CLUSTER_DATA_ELEMENT';
```

this request give me this value :

```
cluster_values
----------------------------
'Gender,ResidenceAddress'
```

The value that I want to get is this : a quote on each element :  'Gender','ResidenceAddress'

```
cluster_values
----------------------------
'Gender','ResidenceAddress'
```

Plz can someone help me fixing this thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
SELECT regexp_replace(value, '([^,]+)', '''\1''', 'g') AS cluster_values 
FROM process_configuration pc 
WHERE pc.parameter = 'CLUSTER_DATA_ELEMENT';

       cluster_values        
-----------------------------
 'Gender','ResidenceAddress'
(1 row)
```